# momentjs isValid is returning false when it should be true and visa versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, momentjs

Using HTML, javascript and jQuery I am importing a date from MS excel using "xlsx.full.min.js". I have set the date field in MS Excel to text so MS Excel does not change its format when exported. Once imported I then parse the table created to validate each field. To validate the date field I use:

```
var dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
alert("$(this).text(): " + $(this).text());
alert(moment(moment($(this).text()).format(dateFormat),dateFormat,true).isValid());
```

When the MS Excel date field contains "13/12/2018" false is returned. When the MS Excel date field contains "12/13/2018" true is returned. Both these values are displayed in the alert so I know they are being passed correctly.

As I have set the date format to "DD/MM/YYYY" why does that format fail and  "MM/DD/YYYY" pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MomentJS converts the date from string into its object before performing operations on it. If format is not specified, it assumes default formats. The parse operation is explained here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

So, in your case you have to pass the dateformat while moment object is created. Like this:

```
var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";
moment("12/13/2018",dateFormat).isValid() //will return false
moment("13/12/2018",dateFormat).isValid() //will return true
```

Update:

MomentJS allows date to be parsed even if the specified date contains other characters apart from the format. For eg., "1A/2B/2018" will be considered as a valid date as "1/2/2018".

Inorder to avoid that, and check the format and date to match exactly, moment object should be passed an additional boolean to enable strict mode.

```
moment("1A/2B/2018", dateFormat).isValid() //will return true
moment("1A/2B/2018", dateFormat, true).isValid() //will return false
```

Comment: On further testing "R2C5" is returned as a valid date using moment($(this).text(),dateFormat).isValid()

Comment: Hi. I updated the answer with the reason why "R2C5" is considered as valid date. Create moment object in strict mode inorder to avoid that.